# Sending data to firebase: data.push() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to send data to firebase using html and Jquery. Here is my code:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>-->
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "demoAPIkey",
        authDomain: "demoAuthDomain",
        databaseURL: "demoDBurl",
        projectId: "demoProjectID",
        storageBucket: "demo.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "demoSendingID"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        //make a variable to keep track of data coming from firebase
        var data= [];

        //create new connection to firebase
        var ref= new Firebase('http://demoDBurl/food');

        //listen to data updates from firebase
        ref.on("value", function (snapshot){
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            //when the data updates at firebase, put it in the data variable
            data= snapshot.val();
        })

        //Entire Form (handler)
        $('#saveFoodForm').on('click',function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);
            console.log("Submit to Firebase");

            //disable submit button
            $form.find("#saveForm").prop('disabled', true);

            //get values to send to Firebase
            var titleToSend = $('#foodTitle').val();
            console.log(titleToSend);

            var descriptionToSend = $('#foodDescription').val();
            console.log(descriptionToSend);

            var categoryToSend= $('#foodCategory').val();
            console.log(categoryToSend);

            //take the values from the form, and put them in an object
            var newFood = {
                "description": descriptionToSend,
                "title": titleToSend,
                "type": categoryToSend
            };

            //put new object in data array
            data.push(newFood);
            //send the new data to Firebase
            ref.set(data, function(err){
                if(err)
                {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    })
</script>
```

I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.push is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index.html:61)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs:

> val() returns any type
>
> Extracts a JavaScript value from a DataSnapshot.
>
> Depending on the data in a DataSnapshot, the val() method may return a scalar type (string, number, or boolean), an array, or an object. It may also return null, indicating that the DataSnapshot is empty (contains no data).

This is `data= snapshot.val();` returning an object, something like this:

```
data is { "name": "Ada", "age": 36 }
```

So the variable `data` contains an object that is why it is not working.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val